# Come off/come out - which is more appropriate to use in the given context?

Tags: idioms

I'm just going to **come off** clean and say I stole the necklace.

I'm just going to **come out** clean and say I stole the necklace.

I looked up **come out** and **come off** and using **come out** here seems more logical. Am I right?
Is it wrong to use **come off** here?

Answer (score 1):

The idiom you are looking for is "come clean," meaning "admit" or "confess." Neither "come off clean" nor "come out clean" are idiomatic. "Come out" by itself has a meaning that is the same as "reveal oneself" and so can be used by extension to mean "admit" or "confess." According to ngram and my personal experience, "come clean" is not as common as "come out."